# GIgya Native Login without using Facebook and Twitter Account

Tags: ios, xcode5, gigya

Following code that i am using to login but i am getting a `Null` response

```
- (IBAction) signInPressed : (id)sender

{

[super signInPressed:sender];


 NSLog(@"ACCLoginViewController_iPhone Sign-IN Pressed");



//Load the Gigya login UI component, passing this View Controller as a delegate.



 GSRequest *request  =  [GSRequest requestForMethod:@"accounts.login"];



[request.parameters setObject:self.emailField.text forKey:@"loginID"];



 [request.parameters setObject:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"password"];



 request.parameters[@"loginID"] = @"email";



[request sendWithResponseHandler:^(GSResponse *response, NSError *error) {


if (!error) {

NSLog(@"the resposne = %@",response);

 }

 else {

  // Check the error code according to the GSErrorCode enum, and handle it.


 NSLog(@"the Error = %@",error.description);


 }

 }];



  //  [self loadTabbar];


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically, we would suggest that you download [Gigya's demo XCode project](http://developers.gigya.com/035_Mobile_SDKs/010_iPhone#Demo_Xcode_Project) from their iOS documentation and compare what you are doing differently from the demo project.  But I believe that the demo project is only set up to do socialLogin and you look as if you are attempting to implement Registration-as-a-Service.

Unfortunately, there isn't enough information provided to really help you diagnose your issue.  You will need to provide the code used to initialize the Gigya SDK and any stack trace logs with errors that are being generated.

Additionally, I realize here that you are not using Facebook Native and Twitter logins but I will provide the following feedback regardless, so that you don't run into these problems in the future should you choose to.

There are some very specific "gotchas" when implementing Facebook login with iOS. Facebook requires that Native Mobile applications integrate and only use their native Facebook login flow. If you are implementing Gigya with Facebook, you must follow [Gigya's documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/035_Mobile_SDKs/010_iPhone#Adding_Facebook_Native_Login) on how to enable Facebook Native login so that the Gigya iOS SDK can properly bridge to it.

Comment: Additional information about the Facebook requirement changes can be found here : (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/)

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply..Let me Look in to it.

Comment: Did you inspect the `error` object in the response handler? What does it say?

Comment: Hey i found the issue , when i am addding the Ooyala player framework its showing ...it sounds weird but thats what i found.

Answer (score 1):

In the app delegate you'll need the following.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Gigya initWithAPIKey:@"[api key goes here"];
    return YES;
}
```

In the view controller I'm currently using this code which is working for me.

```
- (void)loginUser:(NSString*)email withPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    if (![[Gigya session] isValid]) {
        GSRequest *request = [GSRequest requestForMethod:@"accounts.login"];
        request.parameters[@"loginID"] = email;
        request.parameters[@"password"] = password;

        [request sendWithResponseHandler:^(GSResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
                NSString* sessionToken = response[@"sessionInfo"][@"sessionToken"];
                NSString* sessionSecret = response[@"sessionInfo"][@"sessionSecret"];
                GSSession* gigyaSession = [[GSSession alloc] initWithSessionToken:sessionToken secret:sessionSecret];
                [Gigya setSession:gigyaSession];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Already logged in. Logout first.");
    }
}
```